# Coin spinning on smooth table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rigid-body-dynamics

A coin radius $r$ spins on a smooth table with its plane at a small angle $\theta$ to the horizontal. Show that the head on the coin, viewed from above, appears to rotate with angular velocity $\sqrt{(g/r)}\ \theta^{3/2}$, where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

This is problem 30 in the Cavendish Problems in Classical Physics. I am currently trying to work through the 265 problems in this classic collection, but have got stuck on this one.

A few points. (1) the question is slightly ambiguous. I assume "its plane" refers to the coin. I suppose it could refer to the table, but then the question would not make much sense.

(2) Suppose it is a classic top problem. In principle, that seems possible because the moment of the normal force from the table allows precession. Here precession just means the rotation of the point of contact with the table, whereas the spin corresponds to the rotation of the head of the coin viewed from above. So that we are presumably asked to show that the spin is $\sqrt{(g/r)}\ \theta^{3/2}$. That seems slow. For example, $\theta<0.1$ rad, so taking $g/r=1000$ gives 1 rad/s.

(3) But persevering anyway, take the origin at the centre of the coin with the usual Euler angles (rotate the table frame through $\phi$ about $z$-axis, then $\theta$ about $x$-axis), the standard Euler equations with no nutation, constant spin of $\dot{\psi}$ about the $z$ axis in the new frame, and constant precession $\dot{\phi}$ seems to give me $$\frac{1}{2}mr^2\dot{\phi}\dot{\psi}+\frac{1}{4}mr^2\dot{\phi}^2\sin\theta=mgr$$ or $$2\dot{\phi}\dot{\psi}+\dot{\phi}^2\sin\theta=-\frac{4g}{r}$$ I cannot see how that equation is compatible with the required result. [Maybe I got the sign of $mgr$ wrong, but I can't get it to work with either sign.]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Interesting problem, but please note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: @JohnRennie Can you name a single university that sets starred Cavendish problems as homework? Some of them are quite difficult!

Comment: @stafusa Do you really think that is a typical homework problem? I have belonged to the math SE site for many years. Yes, I have watched many people abuse the system by just putting up all their homework questions without apparently making any effort themselves, but there is the opposite danger of not actually providing much useful help. Things that are instantly obvious to one person may hold another up for hours - way beyond what is useful.

Comment: Please, don't pay too much attention to "homework", there's a reason I bold-faced "**type**" in my comment - it doesn't have to have anything to do with being an actual homework. At Physics SE we intend the questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the OP, and prefer conceptual questions. After a lot of discussion, it was decided we wanted to avoid becoming a repository for solved problems (no matter how useful that can be). No one is suggesting you're abusing the system at all - it's simply a blanket 'ban' on this type of question.

Comment: And, no that's not a typical homework problem at all, I meant it when I called it interesting. Actually, having already taught (introductory) mechanics courses myself, to me the solution is not obvious at all.

Comment: @stafusa Thanks for the reply. I guess I lumped you together with John Rennie who had tagged the question as homework-and-exercises a few hours earlier. That was careless of me. Sorry. Turning to your last two comments, conceptual questions are important. But I have always found it hard to grasp concepts at all deeply without doing problems. You must have taken examples classes after brilliant lectures expounding concepts with wonderful clarity only to find that 90% of those in the examples class have missed the most basic points!

Comment: I fully agree problems are essential, and I think virtually everyone else who practices physics does too. Physics and math are like a sport, in the sense that no amount of reading or hearing about it will make you really know how to do it - for that you have to practice. But the same way that a purely mathematical question would be off-topic here (no matter how crucial for physics the answer might be), it was decided long ago that questions about specific problems would too be off-topic. That's a polemic subject and it's raised again every now and then, but for now this is the rule. Best!

Comment: @almagest as a 1st year undergrad at Cambridge in 1980 we were routinely set problems from the Cavendish problems in Physics booklet as homework. Indeed, if you planned to specialise in Physics you were expected to be able to do every problem in the book (I specialised in quantum chemistry so avoided that fate :-). In fact I still have my copy of the booklet bought 38 years ago. There is possibly a more generally interesting question about the dynamics of spinning coins here (for a small and eclectic subset of meanings of *interesting*) but as it stands it is blatantly a homework question.

Comment: Have a look at page 7 http://puhep1.princeton.edu/~kirkmcd/examples/rollingdisk.pdf

Comment: @Farcher - I took advanced classical mechanics from Prof. McDonald (Captain Kirk!) back in 1981.  He loved hard problems, and we felt lucky to solve even one of them (homework or exam) completely. Only class I ever took where 30% was an A...